# Activity not receiving the data from intent

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-intent

My main activity code is here

```html
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val button=findViewById<Button>(R.id.save)
        val loadButton=findViewById<Button>(R.id.load)
        loadButton.setOnClickListener {
            findViewById<EditText>(R.id.username).text
        }
        button.setOnClickListener {
            startActivity(Intent(this,DisplayActivity::class.java).
            putExtra("username",findViewById<TextView>(R.id.username).text))
        }
    }
}
```

My display activity code is here

```html
class DisplayActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display)
        val username=intent.getStringExtra("username").toString();
        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.username1).text=username;
    }
}
```

but when I click the  Save Button(R.id.save) the textview is being displayed as null. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You need to call `putExtra()` *before* calling `startActivity()`, not after.

Comment: After data is added to Intent, it should be passed to startActivity(). Now, after passing an empty intent, we are adding data to the intent. Change the order of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using only `mEditText.text` returns the `Editable` not `String`, try below code:

```
//...
// Rest of the code above
val loadButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.load)
        val mEditText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.username)
        loadButton.setOnClickListener {
            startActivity(Intent(this, DisplayActivity::class.java).apply {
                putExtra("username", mEditText.text.toString()) // <- toString()
            })
        }
```

And get the value like this:

```
class DisplayActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display)
        val username = intent.getStringExtra("username")
        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.username1).text = username
    }
}
```

Comment: hey, It looks like this answer helped you, so giving an +1 up-vote would be nice, thanks.